# Jung Java Graph How to set ID on vertex in view

Tags: java, graph, jung

I use Jung Java library to create simple graph. I want to display vertex's ids on view but now I have rendered only a graph without this. How to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the sample code?  They all do this.

Comment: yes, I have something like that there http://wklej.org/id/979060/ but I dont know which is correct and how to use my own name to vertex. For example I have class Vertex with field String 'name'. I want to use this name

Answer (score 0):

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/PluggableRenderContext.html#setVertexLabelTransformer(org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer)

And supply a Transformer that extracts from your Vertex class its name.